# How do I find the order of a bijection?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Question: List all bijections (permutations) from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ onto $\{1, 2, 3\}$. Find their order and sign.

I understand there will be n! permutations, namely:

$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$,
$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$,
$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$,
$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$,$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    3 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$,
$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$

I understand that order of a permutation $\sigma$ is the smallest possible integer $k$ such that $\sigma^k = \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the identity permutation.

But I am confused by the definition of "identity permutation". If my identity is:
$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
then order $= 0$ and sign = $(-1)^k = (-1)^0 = 1$.
And for: $
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$, order $= 1$, sign $= -1$. And for $
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$ order $= 2$, sign $= 1$.

But if my first bijection from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ onto $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is:
$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
then order $= 0$ and sign $= 1$. So depending on which projection I chose as an identity, the order differs. Can someone clarify?

Comment: The identity function $id_X~:~ X\to X$ is very specifically the function such that $id_X(x) = x$ for all $x\in X$.  You do not get to "decide" which is the identity.  You have as a result, the identity function satisfies $id_X\circ f = f\circ id_X = f$ for all functions $f~:~X\to X$.  This is just like how in a group you have the identity $e$ satisfies $e*x = x*e = x$ for all group members $x$.

Comment: _Every_ permutation $\sigma$ satisfies $\sigma^0=\epsilon$. That's not of interest. The identity permutation satisfies $\epsilon^1=\epsilon$, so it has order $1$. Also, sign and order aren't directly related.

Comment: The order of $\sigma$  is the smallest **positive** integer $k$ such that $\sigma^k = e$. By convention, $\sigma^0 = e$ for any permutation, so  it is meaningless to say the order is 0.

Comment: Summing up all your answers would make a valid answer,I think.

Comment: The identity permutation assigns each element in a set to itself: $id(a) = a$, $id(b) = b$, etc.

Comment: @jordan_glen Thank you! This is what I didn't know.

Comment: Glad to help, BnF76!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity is not something you choose; the identity means the permutation that fixes each element, so the first one you considered is the identity permutation. Secondly, the order of the identity permutation is $1$, because $\epsilon^1=\epsilon$ (the order must be positive). The order of $
\sigma_1=\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{Bmatrix}
$ is $2$ because $\sigma_1$ is not the identity permutation, but if you compose it with itself, you get the identity, so $\sigma_1^2=\epsilon$. The order of $\sigma_2=\begin{Bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{Bmatrix}$ is $3$ because $\sigma_2\neq \epsilon$ and $\sigma_2^2\neq \epsilon$, but $\sigma_2^3=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

You obtain a direct answer to all questions decomposing permutations into a product of disjoint cycles. Concerning permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$, a permutation can be:

- a single $3$-cycle: $(1\,2\,3)$  or $(1\,3\,2)$
- a transposition: $(1\,2)$, $(1\,3)$ or $(2\,3)$
- the empty cycle $(\,)$ (corresponding to the identity)

Now, a cycle of length $k$ has order $k$ and signature $(-1)^{k-1}$.

Comment: The identity permutation represented as a product of disjoint  cycles is most often depicted by $(1)$, short for $(1)(2)(3)$ in this particular case, which is considered a cycle of length $1$, because the order of two or more cycles is the least common multiple of the lengths of its disjoint cycles:  $\operatorname{lcm}(1, 1, 1) = 1$, which is the order of the identity permutation.